# Import XML files in MS Access using an XSL transformation

Tags: xml, vba, ms-access, xslt

What I'm trying to do: There is an automation system which produces like 10k XML files. I want to read all that files into a MS Access Database. In order to import the files (with the VBA `ImportXML` function) I need to transform the files with the VBA `FormatXML` function using an XSL stylesheet.

I googled some stuff, but it seems like I can't get it to work. This is what an XML file looks like (based on confidentiality reasons I cant show a real file, but the structure looks like that):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-16"?>
<Album xmlns="x-schema:ConfigFileSchema.xml">
    <Informations>
        <General>
            <Name>Name of Album</Name>
            <Band>Name of Band</Band>
        </General>
        <Parameters>
            <Parameter>
                <ParamName>Length of Album</ParamName>
                <ParamValue>57:16</ParamValue>
            </Parameter>
            <Parameter>
                <ParamName>Year</ParamName>
                <ParamValue>2020</ParamValue>
            </Parameter>
        </Parameters>
        <Tracks>
            <Track>
                <Trackdef>
                    <TrackName>Name of Track</TrackName>
                    <TrackLength>3:30</TrackLength>
                </Trackdef>
                <Parameters>
                    <Parameter>
                        <ParamName>Features</ParamName>
                        <ParamValue>...</ParamValue>
                    </Parameter>
                    <Parameter>
                        <ParamName>Some other Parameters</ParamName>
                        <ParamValue>...</ParamValue>
                    </Parameter>
                    <Parameter>
                        <ParamName>Some other Parameters</ParamName>
                        <ParamValue>...</ParamValue>
                    </Parameter>
                </Parameters>
            </Track>
            <Track>
                <Trackdef>
                    <TrackName>Name of Track</TrackName>
                    <TrackLength>3:30</TrackLength>
                </Trackdef>
                <Parameters>
                    <Parameter>
                        <ParamName>Features</ParamName>
                        <ParamValue>...</ParamValue>
                    </Parameter>
                    <Parameter>
                        <ParamName>Some other Parameters</ParamName>
                        <ParamValue>...</ParamValue>
                    </Parameter>
                    <Parameter>
                        <ParamName>Some other Parameters</ParamName>
                        <ParamValue>...</ParamValue>
                    </Parameter>
                </Parameters>
            </Track>
        </Tracks>
    </Informations>
</Album>
```

I tried to do some very easy transformations to get the output XML from TransformXML to look like that:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Information>
    <Track>
        <Parameter>
            <ParamName>Features</ParamName>
            <ParamValue>...</ParamValue>
        </Parameter>
        <Parameter>
            <ParamName>Some other Parameters</ParamName>
            <ParamValue>...</ParamValue>
        </Parameter>
    </Track>
    <Track>
        <Parameter>
            <ParamName>Features</ParamName>
            <ParamValue>...</ParamValue>
        </Parameter>
        <Parameter>
            <ParamName>Some other Parameters</ParamName>
            <ParamValue>...</ParamValue>
        </Parameter>
    </Track>
</Information>
```

Using this XSLT:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:template match="/Album/Informations/Tracks/Track/Parameters">
        <Information>
            <xsl:for-each select="child::Parameter">
                <Parameter>
                    <xsl:copy-of select="child::ParamName"/>
                    <xsl:copy-of select="child::ParamValue"/>
                </Parameter>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </Information>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Sadly it doesn't do anything, a blank file is produced.
I hope that somebody can point out what I'm doing wrong here.

Comment: Closing as a duplicate. No criticism intended; you couldn't be expected to know that hundreds of other people have asked the same question in different ways. But the answer is always the same: search for "XSLT default namespace"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were missing the fact that all of your elements are in a default namespace defined on your element

```
<Album xmlns="x-schema:ConfigFileSchema.xml">
```

You have to define that namespace in your XSLT as well to properly access its elements. This can be achieved with the attribute

```
xmlns:x="x-schema:ConfigFileSchema.xml"
```

on your `xsl:stylesheet` element. To get rid of this namespace in your output, also add the attribute

```
exclude-result-prefixes="x"
```

to the `xsl:stylesheet` element.
So the whole stylesheet could look like the following. To get unique parameters it depends on the `TrackName` being unique, because it is used in creating the key value. Of course you can change that to another unique value (but do it in both places - the definition and the usage).

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:x="x-schema:ConfigFileSchema.xml" exclude-result-prefixes="x">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" />
    <xsl:key name="params" match="x:Parameters/x:Parameter" use="concat(x:ParamName,../../x:Trackdef/x:TrackName)" />

    <xsl:template match="text()" />

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <Information>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*" />
        </Information>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="/x:Album/x:Informations/x:Tracks/x:Track">
        <Track>
            <xsl:for-each select="x:Parameters/x:Parameter[generate-id() = generate-id(key('params',concat(x:ParamName,../../x:Trackdef/x:TrackName))[1])]">
                <Parameter>
                    <ParamName><xsl:value-of  select="x:ParamName"/></ParamName>
                    <ParamValue><xsl:value-of select="x:ParamValue"/></ParamValue>
                </Parameter>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </Track>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Its output is:**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Information>
  <Track>
    <Parameter>
      <ParamName>Features</ParamName>
      <ParamValue>...</ParamValue>
    </Parameter>
    <Parameter>
      <ParamName>Some other Parameters</ParamName>
      <ParamValue>...</ParamValue>
    </Parameter>
  </Track>
  <Track>
    <Parameter>
      <ParamName>Features</ParamName>
      <ParamValue>...</ParamValue>
    </Parameter>
    <Parameter>
      <ParamName>Some other Parameters</ParamName>
      <ParamValue>...</ParamValue>
    </Parameter>
  </Track>
</Information>
```